# Limit included php file

Tags: php, limit

Im using a php include and i want to limit how much is shown at the first page:

1.php

```
<?php include('dynpage/some_text.htm'); ?>
```

2.htm

```
    <p style="margin-left: 80px;"> <strong>some title nr.1</strong></p>
    <p>Some text nr.1</p> 

    <strong>some title nr.2</strong>
    <p><strong>NB!</strong>some really long text</p>
```

i want that "1.php" is showing only "some title nr.1" and "Some text nr.1"

i tried different codes i found from internet but none of them worked.

Thank you

Comment: Show us what you tried so we don't wind up repeating it.

Comment: $text = include('dynpage/some_text.htm');
echo substr($text, 0, 50);
//--NEXT--//
$text = substr(include('dynpage/some_text.htm'), 0, 50);
echo $text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will have to make the logic to display limited data on 2.htm (I suggest make it a php file).
Pass a parameter to the second php file and based on it display the data.

Something like include file like "2.php?showless=true"

On 2.php write.

```
 $showless = $_GET['showless']

 if($showless =='true'){
   echo // what you want to show
 }{
   echo // for other cases show everything.
 }
```

Comment: can you make an example or some thing?

Comment: Added an example see if that helps.

Comment: actualy 2.htm is not in my server (i for got to mention) i made an extra file for including 2.htm into php. what now i can do with it to make it happen?

Comment: If the content is static u can directly copy the part to php. What is the logic to copy content? If its complex u can use dom parser.